# How to build multiple module in one apk?

Tags: android

I have 4 module in one project.See image below. App named module is main module. So I want to make one apk with all module.

[This figure shows all module with app named main module and build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhimm.png)

Comment: If App module uses all other modules in dependency, then when you will build APK - you will get one APK. But in your case I don't see other modules in dependency section of gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your **settings.gradle** file and make sure you have the following:

`include ':app', ':OfflineMapp', ':findhike', ':sharelocation', ':weather'`

That should work for you.

Comment: @Ananth for your main app module you need to include the other modules in your dependencies block. Adding these compile project(':OfflineMapp'), compile project(':findhike'), compile project(':sharelocation'), compile project(':weather')